# base64 clear cache? - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I have a page where I created a base64 image from a file input selection, which creates a canvas image and allows user to Upload it to Parse.

It works perfect the very first time the user goes to upload, howeve,r if they try and upload another image.. it does but also keeps a copy of the last base64 image and uploads that as well.

Is it possible to clear the base64 url from the page?  I'm a bit new to working with base64.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well I came up with a simple solution, to just reload the window after the upload completes which solves it for me.  Not exactly the answer but it's a solution that works, for now.